# Get Control Path In project

Tags: c#, winforms

I have button in my form it name is btnAdd
I want to get full path of this button in my project like this

MyAppName.namespace.MyFormName.btnAdd

Comment: Why do you *need* this? How are you planning to use such information?

Comment: To determine the user’s permissions by using the control path, I think it is the best way to shorten the code and time in defining the user’s permissions

Comment: I think the control name on its own (using the form name to disambiguate between forms) or something in the `tag` property could be better options. Even better, a custom or inherited control that does the validation using dedicated properties may be much preferable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btnAdd.GetType().FullName` will get you the fully qualified name of the *type* of `btnAdd`.

If you want the name of the variable along with the fully qualified name of the form in which it is defined, you could do something like this:

```
string name = this.GetType().FullName + "." + nameof(btnAdd);
```

...where `this` refers to the form and can be replace by any other type such as for example `typeof(Form1)`.

Comment: The second option is the answer. `btnAdd.GetType().FullName` will just return `System.Windows.Forms.Button`.